# New table with selectcolumns

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the next table:

[image: Table 1]

And I need the next results:

[image: Table Results]

In every day I have between, agreement and end-Date, I need to show a data per region.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please formulate this as a question and edit the title to be descriptive of the specific issue you're asking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably isn't the most efficient way.

```
Table = 
SELECTCOLUMNS(
    FILTER(
        CROSSJOIN(CALENDARAUTO();Table1)
        ;[Date]>=[StartDate] && [Date]<=[EndDate]
    )
    ;"Date";[Date]
    ;"REGION";[Category]
    ;"Amount";[Amount]
)
```

OR

```
Table = 
SELECTCOLUMNS(
    GENERATE('Table1';DATESBETWEEN('Date'[Date];[StartDate];[EndDate]))
    ;"Date";[Date]
    ;"Category";[Category]
    ;"Amount";[Amount]
)
```

I am not summarizing but your could do it with SUMMARIZE.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am trying for a while. First option works fine.